# Django how to show all comment as child parent relationship in HTML template?

Tags: python, django

I want to show my all child objects under it's parent in my html template. How to do it in Django?

**#html**

```
{%for i in contact %}
  {% if not i.parent %}#shwing only parent objects
       ticket #parent_id{{i.message}}
       #here I want to list all child object of my parent   
  {%endif%}     
  {%endfor%}
```

here is my **models.py**:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='contact_user')
       name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
       email = models.EmailField(max_length=500)
       message = models.CharField(max_length=2000,blank=True,null=True)
       parent =models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            null=True, blank=True, related_name='contact_parent')
       sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,)
```

here is my views.py

```
def UserProfileView(request):
   userinfo = UserManagement.objects.filter(username=request.user)
   userprofile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
   contact = Contact.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    
    
   form = TicketForm(request.POST or None)
   if request.method == "POST":
       if form.is_valid():
          form.instance.user = request.user
          messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO,'You ticket submitted sucessfully')
          form.save() 
          return redirect('members:user-profile-private')

   else:
        form = TicketForm()


   context={"userinfo":userinfo,"userprofile":userprofile,"form":form,"contact":contact}
   return render(request,"members/privateprofile.html",context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

query:

```py
Contact.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True)
```

template:

```html
{% for parent in contact %}
    <h1>{{ parent.name }}</h1>
    {% if parent.contact_parent.count %}
        <ul>
        {% for child in parent.contact_parent.all %}
            <li>{{ child.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, I think you should change the `related_name` to something like `contact_children` or just `children`, remember this should represent the opposite of the field in OneToMany relationship, example:

```py
parent = models.ForeignKey(
    "self",
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    related_name="contact_children", # opposite of field
)
```

And to avoid doing too many queries in your template you could use `prefetch_related`:

```py
Contact.objects.prefetch_related('contact_children').filter(parent__isnull=True)
```

And the template:

```html
{% for parent in contact %}
    <h1>{{ parent.name }}</h1>
    {% if parent.contact_children.count %}
        <ul>
        {% for child in parent.contact_children.all %}
            <li>{{ child.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Looks more understandable right?

Comment: Jonathan Quispe Thanks for your answer but didn't work.

Comment: Jonathan Quispe getting all objects in every bock

Comment: That is weird, I've tested the code and it works well `.contact_children.all` only lists elements that have the current item as parent. Anyway in your template you just need to add another loop to list the children, something like `{% for child in i.parent.contact_parent.all %} ... {% endfor %}` in the place you are mention in your template, good luck!

Comment: Jonathan Quispe thanks it worked after added this line ` {% for child in i.parent.contact_parent.all %} ... {% endfor %}` as you mentioned above comment. Thanks again

Comment: Jonathan Quispe can you please  explain little bit about the cod how it's working as parent and child relationship??? It's help me to understand concept of your code.

Comment: Sure, when an OneToMany relationship -like the `parent` field in your model- is created, two things happen: first there is a new field in the current model it is used to save the id of the related model, and second there is a new member in the related model called as the `related_name` you called it `contact_parent` this is an ObjectManager similar to `.objects` but it filters just all related models, in this case, the related model is the self-model so `.parent` will access to the parent model and `.contact_parent` to will access to the children

Comment: In your template, you are using `{% if not i.parent %}` to filter the contacts without parent, instead of that I just do the same but in the query `Contact.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True)` so the first loop is not needed anymore, then I just create another loop to list the children with `.contact_parent`, remember this is an ObjectManager that filter only contacts that have the current contact as parent, that's why I'm using `.contact_parent.all` to access all related children, also that's why I suggest renaming `contact_parent -> contact_children` because it accesses to children

Comment: @JonathanQuispe: This absolutely works.